# Python zip() function with error message

Tags: python

I tried summing two lists using zip with list comprehension and it works for me.

```
a=[1,2,3]

b=[4,5,6]

three = [sum(i) for i in zip(a,b)]

print(three)
```

output:
[5, 7, 9]

Next i tried using a function .And i end getting this error message:

```
def sum(a,b):

    for i in zip(a,b):

       return sum(i)

print(sum([1,2,3], [5,6,7]))
```

> return sum(i)
>
> TypeError: sum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Please make me understand where i m going wrong.

Comment: You're overriding the builtin function `sum` with your own function, and you end up making a recursive call. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

the error is on the return line 'return sum(i)', the sum function that you'd defined take two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things, `zip` combines the two lists so if you were to try:

`for i, j in zip(a, b):
    print(i, j)`

You would get something like:

`1 4
 2 5
 3 6`

You're getting an error because `sum` is a built in function to python, so if you were to change your function name to anything else, it shouldn't have the same issue.

I think what you are looking for is concatenating the lists and then calling `sum()` on the resulting list?

change your method to:

```
def add_lists(a, b):
   c = a + b
   return sum(c)
```